# How can I select and update a column value in single query with codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My database contains a table, in this table I have a column "Earned". This column contains some value and I have to add some amount to this column(Earned).

Right now I am able to do in this way..

```
        $this->db->select('Earned');
        $this->db->where('CustMobile', $LinkMobile);
        $query_result=$this->db->get('customers');
        $result=$query_result->row();

        $finalAmount=$result->Earned+$Commsion;

        $this->db->set('Earned', $finalAmount);
        $this->db->where('CustMobile', $LinkMobile);
        $this->db->update('customers');
```

I want to know how I can update this value with a single query?

My database looks like this.

[image: I want to change this circled value 1100 to 2000]

I want to change this circled value 1100 to 2000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE `customers` SET `Earned` = `Earned` + $Commsion WHERE `CustMobile` = $LinkMobile");
```

---

**Explanation**

**`Earned = Earned + $Commsion`** ==> This part will grab the value of the field and add the new value.

> *Example* - If `$Commsion` is 1000 and your respective **`Earned`** field is 1100. So it will update as `2100`.

Answer (score 2):

although you have accepted the answer and but I would like to add the active record query for it:

```
$this->db->set('Earned', 'Earned +'. $Commsion .'',false);
$this->db->where('CustMobile', $LinkMobile);
$this->db->update('customers');
```

Comment: This one is way cleaner when you use the query builder.